# How to speed up optimization routine in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, numpy

I have a constrained optimization problem for which I use the `sp.optimize.minimize()` function, with the **SLSQP** (Sequential Least Square Quadratic Programming) method.

A single access to the  actual objective function is computationally quick. My problem is the `minimize()` routine does many fast access and then suddenly stops for a long time then does many fast iterations and waits and so on. So on the whole its slow, so is there anything I can do to alleviate this problem?

Any alternatives for constrained optimization other that **SLSQP** in scipy like `PyOpt` for example?

Comment: "does many fast access and then suddenly stops for a long time then does many fast iterations and waits and so on" Do you know what is causing this? What's your system memory like -- is it possible that it's thrashing against the GC?

Comment: "Thrashing against GC" is a new term for me. I am assuming thrashing is something like memory leak. If its thrashing don't you think it will crash? But mine doesn't, it alternates between a swarm of fast access and long waits. Is it possible that it tries to find the gradient or something by couple of quick access and does some deep calculations? I don't know how SLSQP operates. I don't get "what's your system memory like" its a remote machine in which I do ssh and run the program. Its a 32GB machine. Also doesn't python handle all memory leaks on its own?

Comment: If memory were leaking, it wouldn't be handled. What you mean is that python manages it's memory through refrence-counting and garbage collection. The term "thrashing against GC" refers to a phenomena where a lot of allocations happen fast, ramping up memory consumption, and then the GC kicks in and due to it's nature pauses the process for a short while. This hickuppy behaviour can be possibly suppressed for the calculation's time through use of the gc-model. But this only makes sense if that's the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks @deets, I see.Can you please elaborate on what is "use of gc-model"? Again are you familiar with functioning of SLSQP?

Comment: Sorry, gc-model was supposed to be gc-module. And that's documented in the standard lib documentation and there you can turn off the gc, and see if the behaviour improves. And no, I'm not familiar with SLSQP.

Comment: Could you provide a minimum working example that shows this behavior?

Comment: @ram
Profiling the offending parts of your script may point you at a solution (http://tinyurl.com/lv5j47b)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it turned out, this behavior has nothing to with gc but due to the working of SLSQP. What happens is the algorithm first calculates the jacobian of the function by random perturbation and then does some calculation. After I explicitly included a jacobian function the fast access stopped, it ran little slow but ended in a few iterations.